# Function to extract company register number from text string using Regex

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a function which extracts the company register number (German: `handelsregisternummer`) from a given text. Although my regex for this particular problem matches the correct format ([please see demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMmId7/1)), I can not extract the correct company register number.

I want to extract `HRB 142663 B` but I get `HRB 142663`.

Most numbers are in the format `HRB 123456` but sometimes there is the letter `B` attached to the end.

```
import re

def get_handelsregisternummer(string, keyword):

    # https://regex101.com/r/k6AGmq/10
    reg_1 = fr'\b{keyword}[,:]?(?:[- ](?:Nr|Nummer)[.:]*)?\s?(\d+(?: \d+)*)(?: B)?'

    match = re.compile(reg_1)
    handelsregisternummer = match.findall(string)  # list of matched words

    if handelsregisternummer:  # not empty
        return handelsregisternummer[0]
    else:  # no match found
        handelsregisternummer = ""

    return handelsregisternummer
```

Example text scraped from website. Linebreaks make words attached to each other:

```
text_impressum = """"Berlin, HRB 142663 BVAT-ID.: DE283580648Tax Reference Number:"""
```

Apply function:

```
for keyword in ['HRB', 'HRA', 'HR B', 'HR A']:
    handelsregisternummer = get_handelsregisternummer(text_impressum, keyword=keyword)
    if handelsregisternummer: # if list is not empty anymore, then do...
        handelsregisternummer = keyword + " " + handelsregisternummer
        break
    if not handelsregisternummer:  # if list is empty
        handelsregisternummer = 'not specified'
handelsregisternummer_dict = {'handelsregisternummer':handelsregisternummer}
```

Afterwards I get:

```
handelsregisternummer_dict ={'handelsregisternummer': 'HRB 142663'}
```

But I want this:

```
handelsregisternummer_dict ={'handelsregisternummer': 'HRB 142663 B'}
```

Comment: What if you use *non-capturing groups* only in the regex (`reg_1 = fr'\b{keyword}[,:]?(?:[- ](?:Nr|Nummer)[.:]*)?\s?(?:\d+(?: \d+)*)(?: B)?'`), and remove the `handelsregisternummer = keyword + " " + handelsregisternummer`  line? See https://ideone.com/O6XEDS

Comment: Great, I think we are almost there. Is there a way to avoid returning ``Nr`` or ``Nummer``, respectively? These 2 words should just be an indicator. For example ``text_impressum = """"This is an example HRA Nummer 21156"""`` returns ``'HRA Nummer 21156'``  I am interested in ``HRB``. ``HRA``,... and the following numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two capturing groups in the regex to *capture* the keyword and the number, and just match the rest:

```py
reg_1 = fr'\b({keyword})[,:]?(?:[- ](?:Nr|Nummer)[.:]*)?\s?(\d+(?: \d+)*(?: B)?)'
#            |_________|                                   |___________________|
```

Then, you need to concatenate, join all the capturing groups matched and returned with `findall`:

```py
if handelsregisternummer: # if list is not empty anymore, then do...
    handelsregisternummer = " ".join(handelsregisternummer)
    break
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fLphce).

Comment: This looks great. Thank you very much!